# Increase height of an "<li>" with respect to another "<li>"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set the height of a "li" will increase automatically in respect to another "li".

I have paste the sample HTML code.

```
<ul onclick="menu_slide('#sub1')" class="list listred" id="list">

<li onclick="toggle_div('toggle_div0')" class="name">

<span style="color:#fff;"> 

    <a style="color:#fff; text-decoration:none" href="Javascript:void(0)">Banerjee, Sraboni </a>
<br>

 UPN 414 
 </span>
<span style="color:#fff; font-weight:normal;">Billed On  06/13/2013 @ 12:11 pm</span>
<p id="last_event0" style="color:#fff;"> Assigned By Moumita Balasssssssssssssssssssss<br>sssssssssssssssssssssssss .</p>
</li>
<li class="bill">

<div style="">
<div style="display:none" id="checkedicon_0" class="tick_mark_list"> 
    <span style="cursor:pointer" onclick="remove_checkedicon(0, '1092')"><img width="25px" src="images/tick_mark.png"></span> 
</div>   
<!-- Code for message --> 
<!-- Checking whether this provider has any biller message or not starts -->
<div style="padding:6px 8px 0 8px; box-shadow: 0 0 9px -3px #000000 inset;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 9px -3px #000000 inset;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 9px -3px #000000 inset;
-o-box-shadow: 0 0 9px -3px #000000 inset;float:left; border-radius:3px; background: #fff;  position: relative;
    right: 3px;
    top: 3px; visibility: hidden;"><span><img src="images/spech.png"></span>
    </div>
<!-- Checking whether this provider has any biller message or not ends -->
<!--Code for message-->

<!--<a href="add_bill.php?patient_id=&type=Primary" class="but3" style="margin-right:0;"><span>A</span>DD</a>patient_bill_id-->
        <a onclick="open_slide('1092', 'Sraboni Banerjee')" style="margin-right:0;" class="but3" href="Javascript:void(0)"><span>A</span>DD</a>
    <a onclick="unfollow_patient('1092','Primary','2')" class="unfollow" href="Javascript:void(0)"><span>X</span></a>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
    </li>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</ul>
```

Here you can find 2 li inside an ul. I want to increase the height of the second li with first li. Is there anyway in jquery to fix this. I have attach the screen shot for better understanding. [image] . Here you can see in first row height of the right most button become less than the actual height of row.

Comment: where is the relevant code part? i'm lost in your code...

Comment: yes I agree it is very big. But basical I want height of first li will increase with second li. I have use div and paragraph inside li too. If there is any way to increase the height of div dynamical with reference to other div by jquery will be ok for me.

Comment: You specify position as `relative` in the second div. There are no other positions. Do you have a body position set somewhere ? 
Wherever you have mentioned position as relative, do you know its `relative` to *what* ? 

http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: Like @roasted said, need more code to understand how this is working.  We can make guesses, but there really isn't enough to test with.

Comment: Ditto to what Roasted and @Justin said; or rather, more code, but with less fluff.  If we could see your markup without all of that irrelivant inline styling (ie: color, shadow, etc) it would be much easier to read.  Do you have an external stylesheet, or are you working entirely inline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out [the EqualHeights jQuery Plugin](http://www.cssnewbie.com/equalheights-jquery-plugin/#.UcMHYZ3mTct)

> The plugin’s functionality is so simple because it’s designed to do only one thing: set all elements you specify to the same height.

Demo page:
http://www.cssnewbie.com/example/equal-heights/plugin.html

Comment: I think it may help me. let me try it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple to do what you're asking.  The complexity will come when you start having pages full of the elements in question, and if you want it to fire on a resize that may occur outside code (if that happens).  This is a basic example, but can be expanded upon...

http://jsfiddle.net/bfE4L/

The main code in question is...

```
$("#li2").height($("#li1").height());
```